# Jinja2 and Angular2 template variables after Angular-cli build

Tags: javascript, angular, jinja2, angular-cli, webapp2

Can you use Jinja2 template variables in an Angular2 app after the app has been built via Angular-Cli, and if so, how?

I currently am passing the generated index.html file that is built through the Jinja2 template engine with server-side parameters. Any template parameters passed work only within index.html. What if I want to pass these along to component templates within Angular2?

*ng-build file structure:*

```
dist
|-assets/
|-inline.bundle.js
|-main.bundle.js
|-index.html
|-styles.bundle.css
|-styles.bundle.map
|-vendor.bundle.js
```

***index.html***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- this {{ test_param }} is properly rendered via Jinja2 -->
    <title>{{ test_param }}</title>
    <base href='/'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="styles.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
<body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
```

*inside **main.component.html**, a template which is part of main.component.ts in ng2*:

```
<!-- this {{ test_param }} does not render to anything since it is generated and built by ng2-cli -->
<h1>{{ test_param }}</h1>
```

Changing the ng2 interpolation for the template for the main component does not change anything since angular-cli still needs to build.

Quoting out the curly braces via `{{ '{' }} and {{ '}' }}` returns the literal `{{ test_param }}` in the component.

Comment: Even , I'm also looking for this. Any answers.?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible.